# Liquibase: Add changesets for new database

Tags: oracle, postgresql, liquibase

I have an existing schema defined using Liquibase for PostgreSQL. I am adding support for Oracle and this requires significant changes. Some create-table tags would work by just changing data-types, some would not (requiring sql changes). Current changelog-schema file has multiple create-table statements under single change-set (I know this is not a good design, but thats what I now have to deal with) and in order to reuse some of those create-table tags, I may have to remove them from existing change-set and add to a new one. The liquibase code is injected using Spring, as a result of which, whenever my application starts, it would check the database for any changes. Will refactoring (as mentioned) affect the hash code that liquibase creates on existing database? If so, in that case I understand the option is to replicate create-table tags for Oracle.

I am relatively new to liquibase. Please correct me if I am wrong in my understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would attempt to create cross platform changesets by using Liquibase's feature to [modify the generated SQL](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/modify_sql) to match the target database.

Comment: The way I managed right now is to parameterize the column data-type, making shorter sequence/constraint names. I had used couple of table names which are reserved words in Oracle, so had to parameterize them too. **Importantly:** LiquiBase computes an MD5 checksum for each change set in changelog files, and fails if differs from that stored in the database table "ChangeLogLock". LiquiBase uses the triplet (id, author, filename) as a unique ID for a change set. Duplicate triplets cause LiquiBase to fail.